# java.lang.NullPointerException query invoke

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm new in Java EE and I'm trying to create a method that collects information from a database. It's giving me the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.universite.bean.checkmatiere.check(checkmatiere.java:49)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invokeMethod(BeanELResolver.java:779)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:528)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:257)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:134)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:224)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:227)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:85)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:183)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

This is my `check` method. It gives me an error when I invoke `trouver` method:

```
 public void check() {
    etudiant =(Etudiant) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("etudiant");
    n=etudiant.getniveau();
    result =matiereDao.trouver( n );
    if(result.size()!=0) {
        Iterator<Matiere> stIterator=result.iterator();
        while(stIterator.hasNext()){
         matiere=(Matiere)stIterator.next();
         FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("matire: "+ matiere.getNom() );
         FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage( null,message );

        nummatiere=matiere.getIdmatiere();
            private List<Chapitre> result1;
    /*line 49*/  result1 =chapitredao.trouver( nummatiere );
          if (result1!= null)
         {if(result1.size()!=0)
                        {
                            Iterator<Chapitre> stIterator1=result1.iterator();
                            while(stIterator1.hasNext()){
                             chapitre=(Chapitre)stIterator1.next();
                             FacesMessage message1 = new FacesMessage( "chapitre: "+chapitre.getNomchapitre() );
                             FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage( null,message1 );

                            }
            }          }


         }

    }
    else  {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage( "echec !" );
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage( null,message );
    }
```

And this is my "trouver" function

```
      private static final String JPQL_SELECT_PAR_nummatiere= "SELECT ufFROM              Chapitre uf where uf.nummatiere=:nummatiere";
               private static final String PARAM_nummatiere       = "nummatiere";
               public List<Chapitre> trouver(int nummatiere  ) throws DAOException {

Query requete1 = entitymanager.createQuery( JPQL_SELECT_PAR_nummatiere );
requete1.setParameter( PARAM_nummatiere, nummatiere);
try {
    results2 =  requete1.getResultList();
} catch ( NoResultException e ) {
return null;
} catch ( Exception e ) {
throw new DAOException( e );
}
return results2;
}
```

Thanks for any help you can give.  I've been stuck with this error for three days now.

Comment: Is it related to JSF? Tag as such, if it is.

Comment: What's in the 49 line at your checkmatiere class?

Comment: in line 49 there's  result1 =chapitredao.trouver( nummatiere );

Comment: Have you tried debugging ?

Comment: @Lion this is unrelated to JSF, it is a basic Java programming problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you say your error is when you call `trouver()` in this line:

```
result1 = chapitredao.trouver(nummatiere);
```

Then the problem is that you haven't initialized the `chapitredao` field. That is, possibly somewhere around you class you have:

```
private <TYPE> chapitredao;
```

Make it like:

```
private <TYPE> chapitredao = new <TYPE>();
```

Such as, for example:

```
private ChapitreDao chapitredao = new ChapitreDao();
```

Or get it via, maybe `ChapitreDao chapitredao = ChapitreDao.getInstance();`Or initialize it via constructor (or even via injection).

Comment: i initialized chapitredao = new ChapitreDao(); but the problem still persist i think that every time he invokes a search via the method trouver he returns a javax.persistence.NoResultException

Comment: i don'think it's an initialisation problem because he didn't invoke it when i used matieredao(and it works) @acdcjunior

Comment: You see, by the stacktrace, it never enters trouve method. You should put a System.out.print() at the first line of that method just to make sure it is never entered.

Comment: @user2281794 is your `chapitredao` an EJB? If yes, then you don't even need to initialize it, just add the `@EJB` annotation when declaring the variable and let the Java EE web app server inject the bean.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza thanks this have resolved the problem i'm really gratful

Comment: @user2281794 what resolved your problem? acdcjunior answer or my `@EJB` annotation advice?